# Remove the time between the dates in highstock

Tags: highcharts

My graph is having time between dates.I want to display just the date.
As Highstock is responsive,the time is removed once I minimize the browser and only dates are shown.
I have tried dateTimeLabelFormats in xAxis and tickInterval.
Those doesn't seem to work.

Help is appreciated

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsFiddle or show your code here?

Comment: You can use tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner to define your dynamic ticks or use tickInterval to define "distance" between ticks http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval